# ASP.NET User Control in modal pop-up on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, dialog

So I have a control, userlogin.ascx, that I want to pop up with a modal effect when a user tries to access certain pages when not logged in. How would I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: I would go about reading the examples on the Ajax control toolkit website (http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx), for example

Comment: This is a bit more difficult than just opening a modal window, since .NET will by default try to redirect you to the login page that is setup in your web.config...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you use the jQuery dialog plugin, you can load a URL in to the dialog.
So do a plain .ASPX page, load your .ascx into that, and pop the url into the modal:

```
$("#divid").load('http://your.aspx').dialog({modal:true});
```

Note that you need to have the a div with id "divid" (or whatever) on the calling page for this to work. More here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#options

Further to that, you can place this in a javascript function in a .js - in the pages where you want to pop this, 1) make sure you have your div there, and 2) in the page load, check Request.IsAuthenticated, and if it's not use the Page.ScriptManager to call your .js function.

If you want to keep things neat, roll that functionality into a little .acsx control, and then you simply drop that on the pages where you want to enforce people being logged in.

Finally, bear in mind that javascript can be turned off, so you might want to consider the safety of the overall approach... If you want to stick with this, it's possible to do some javascript detection when a user first hits your site, use e.g. jquery to asynch call a .asmx or similar, and set e.g. Session["userHasJavascript"] to true, but again this does not guarantee they don't disable it later.
Short of the long, you're generally better of redirecting to a login page...